# Exceptions happen when using JDBCRealm

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jakarta-ee

How can I debug `javax.servlet.ServletException` caused by `request.login()` method?
Login.java

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    try {       
        request.login(username, password); // Exceptions happen.
        out.println("logged in");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

tomcat server.xml

```
  <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>


<!-- added by myself>
    <Context>
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm" 
          connectionName="root" 
          connectionPassword="password" 
          connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost/forum?autoReconnectForPools=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8" 
          digest="MD5" 
          driverName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
          roleNameCol="role_name" 
          userCredCol="user_pass"
          userNameCol="user_name"
          userRoleTable="user_roles"
          userTable="users" />
     </Context>
```

Exception:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: Login failed  at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.doLogin(AuthenticatorBase.java:963)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.login(AuthenticatorBase.java:943)
>     at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.login(Request.java:2768)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.login(RequestFacade.java:1064)
>     at com.example.Login.doPost(Login.java:55)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Create Session before logging in. Code: `if (request.getUserPrincipal() == null) {
    request.getSession(); // create session
    request.login(username, password);
}`

Comment: How did you populate the password column `user_pass ` in the database? It should be MD5 hashed by the look of it

Comment: @Steve I use `insert into users(user_name, user_pass) values ('1', MD5('1'));`. Just for test.

Comment: @Jay Smith Do you mean comment out the line `request.login(username, password);`? If so, how to test the username and password is correct?`request.getUserPrincipal()` returns null in my program.

Comment: Don't comment this line. If `request.getUserPrincipal()` returns null there is no authenticated user thus you can create session and do login. You can store authenticated user in created session object

Comment: @JaySmith I've tried this,but the same exception occurs.

Comment: is stacktrace of exception complete ? Isn't there `Caused By` ?

Comment: @JaySmith Yes,it's complete. What debug code can I add to troubleshoot this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a `Login fail` because the method that you used to create the hashed password in the database is different from that used by the Tomcat `JDBCRealm`.

Instead of using the MySql `MD5` function, you should use the `digest` tool provided by Tomcat (in the `bin` directory of your Tomcat installation) to generate the hashed password.

For example (with a password of "1"):

```
[steve@Steves-MacBook-Pro apache-tomcat-8.0.18]$ bin/digest.sh -s 0 -a MD5 1
1:$1$c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b
```

I expect that this result (`$1$c4ca4238a0...`) is different from what you will observe in the database table.

Additionally, according to [Tomcat 8 Realm Configuration HOW-TO](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/realm-howto.html#Digested_Passwords), you should digest the values `{username}:{realm}:{cleartext-password}` instead of just `{cleartext-password}` and store that in the database. The `{realm}` value comes from the `<realm-name>` in your web.xml file.

Comment: Yes,it's different.Every time l run the digest command with password '1', the value is different. So how to store the password?

Comment: It seems that you need to specify a `salt` length of `0`.

Comment: @ Steve C I use tomcat-7.0.78. According to doc, I use vaule of `RealmBase.Digest("1:Authentication required:1", "MD5", "UTF-8")` for testing user "1" with password "1" and store it in database. But the same exception still exists.